# Strategy to check if Transactional Replication succeeded

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We would like to use Transactional Replication to replicate data from one source database to recipient databases. If replication succeed it is necessary to notify some other systems in workflow. Is there any way to check, based on some attribute, if replication succeded? What for strategy would you choose to notify, for example cache, that some data are available?

**Update:**
I think I wasn't clear enough. What we want to know is, if entity is already an all subscribers. For example: I insert a new  *Car* and some *Cars* details into two tables in master DB. I want to know if a new *Car* and his details are replicated to all subscribers to able to say: *"Car is online"*

Answer (score 0):

Try and check out [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152758.aspx) detailing a strategy to validate that the replication occurred.

Basically it offers two strategies:

1) Checking row counts.

2) Checking row counts AND running a `CHECKSUM` operation for added robustness.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. The idea is to know when an entity is  already on all subscribers.